# How can I record a pressure map?

Tags: sensor

There are some Dr. Scholl's commercials showing their "foot-doctor-o-matic" station that measures the pressure your feet put down on a mat then tells you what insoles to buy.  How does the thing actually work; what sort of component is able to translate an array of force across a plane into electronic signals?  If the thing cheats and uses temperature, the question still stands; how can I record an array of pressures across a plane?

Comment: I've seen a similar solution which uses really thin pressure sensors (made by Panasonic, I think, can't remember the part number) arranged in a matrix which is then scanned. This one was for a Go flexible mat-style surface, but I guess similar system (and probably cheaper, since Go stones have very low mass) could be used to determine the pressure feet make.

Comment: @nickT, One of the users of a different site often discusses his work with them [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5230361#5230361). He regularly discusses his progress analyzing data. You might get more information from him on this.

Comment: What resolution do you need? I.E. how many sensors, and what distance between sensors. Is there a thickness constraint?

Answer (score 9):

Pressure sensors arranged in a matrix to produce pressure related voltages which are scanned, digitised and analysed. Some pages on the site below say "pizeoelectric" pressure sensing and some say "resistive". Both are feasible.

- A compressible material which varies in resistance between top and bottom surfaces could be arranged in a matrix with each point scanned and measured.
  Think in terms of semiconductor strain gauges, although not necessarily arranged in the usual bridge manner.
- A piezo element will produce a pressure related static voltage which can be scanned and measured.

---

[SPI Sensor productrs Inc](http://www.sensorprod.com/) make a wide range of surface pressure indicating sensors.

---

For a typical foot pad suitable for two feet at once, one system, [The GoTec foot mapping sensor](http://www.sensorprod.com/foot-plate-pressure-sensor.php) has the following specification:

- Technology   Resistive
  Number of Sensors   2,304 (Arranged in a 48 x 48 Matrix)
  Spatial Resolution  0.31 in. (8 mm)
  Sensing Area    15 in. x 15 in. (38 cm x 38 cm)
  Data Resolution 12-bit
  Pressure Range  0.72 to 30 PSI (0.05 to 2.10 kg/cm²)
  Data Acquisition Frequency  180 Hz
  Accuracy    ±10%
  Platform Height 0.25 in. (0.63 cm)
  Weight  9.25 lbs. (4.2 kg)
  Operating System    Windows® XP / 7
  Connection Method   USB / Wireless
  Operating Temp. Range   5°F to 86°F (-15°C to 30°C)

[image]

---

The products shown below closely match your description.
Whether Scholls use the same method is unknown but it seems likely.

Their systems are based in some and maybe in all cases on piezoelectric pressure sensing elements (although "resistive" is mentioned) which are arranged in a matrix and then scanned and digitized by standard techniques.

Their [Tactilus equestrics saddle fitting sensor](http://www.sensorprod.com/dynamic/saddle-pressure-mapping.php) is said to use piezo pressure measurement

- The Tactilus Equestrics® sensor is a matrix-based tactile surface sensor that works by the principle of piezoresistance. Tiny sensing cells cover the entire surface area of the sensor “skin” allowing for discrete spot pressure analysis at any point in the contact region. The Tactilus Equestrics® sensor provides real-time data showing precisely where the pressure points occurs between the saddle and the horse.

[image]

Specification: Note the use of the term "Piezoresistive" which places some doubt on whether the resistive and pizeoxxx systems are in fact the same.

Technology  Piezoresistive
Pressure Range  0 - 5 PSI (0 - 0.35 kg/cm²)
Grid Size   18 x 22 split mat
Sensing Points  388
Total Sensing Area  29.5 x 17.5 in. (75.9 x 44.5 cm)
Scan Speed  Up to 10 hertz
Thickness   30 mils (0.76 mm)
Accuracy    ±10%

["sensor products inc"](http://www.sensorprod.com/) advertise a range of tactile pressure indicating films.

[Foot plate sensor](http://www.sensorprod.com/foot-plate-pressure-sensor.php)

---

Sew-in piezoeresistive sensing material.
Unfortunately the page related to this image was dead :-(

Eeontex conductive fabric used for pressure sensor construction - [data sheets here](http://www.eeonyx.com/datasheets.php?type=eeontex)

[image]

[image]

Maxim - demystifying PR sensors](http://www.maxim-ic.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/871)

- Abstract: Monocrystalline silicon pressure sensors have come into wide use in recent years. Though manufactured with semiconductor technology, they also operate on the resistive principle. The resistance change in a monocrystalline semiconductor (a piezoelectric effect) is substantially higher than that in standard strain gauges, whose resistance changes with geometrical changes in the structure. Conductivity in a doped semiconductor is influenced by a change (compression or stretching of the crystal grid) that can be produced by an extremely small mechanical deformation. Using a signal conditioning integrated circuit to temperature compensate and amplify the signal offers superior performance over discrete circuits.

[PE & PR sensors](http://academic.udayton.edu/markpatterson/ECT459/Piezoelectric%20and%20PiezoSensors.pdf) U.Dayton.

[PE & PR Effects](http://www.comsol.com/multiphysics/piezoresistiveeffects/) - COMSOL demo -  Flash so can't copy live image. Worth a peek.

[Silicon PR sensors](http://js-engineering.com/Assets/SensorsJournal01.pdf)  useful.

[PR design and optimisation](http://microsystems.stanford.edu/wiki/Micro:Piezoresistor_Design_and_Optimization) somewhat off topic but useful and good references.

[Northwestern edu - piezoresistive sensors](http://www.mech.northwestern.edu/FOM/LiuCh06v3_072505.pdf) 36 pages. Textbook chapter. Good.

[Wikipedia - piezoresistive effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoresistive_effect)

---

**"Body mapping":**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The carbon foam that components come on can be used for this. Just sandwich it between to flexible plates with electrodes (veroboard like). The resistance between upper and lower board is a measure for pressure.

I even think the electrodes do not even have to be small and round(ish), you might just pull it off with crosswise wires: left to right on the top and up-down in the bottom. Then just select one wire from the top and scan all wires from the bottom. Then select next wire in the top .... etc.

Didn't test it myself, but it is worth to try as a low cost alternative to real pressure sensonrs.

Comment: I'm not looking for a hobbyist-level solution; I need something more production-level.